# Increment value in range by specific number

Tags: excel, vba, variables, counter, increment

For a work project I'm trying to build an excel sheet that lets a user input a number in a dialogue box (or cell) and once a confirmation button is pressed, all numbers in a specific range shall be incremented by the specific value entered by the user. My range is B2:B100 and all cells are either filled with numbers or are empty.

When the user completes his work they'd enter their value in e.g. cell J3 and then press a toggled button underneath. J3 will be cleared and all values in B2:B100 would be incremented by the number entered.
Any help or direction to resources that would cover this would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In Excel, Press Alt + F11
2) It will open the VBA editor. copy paste the following code in the editor.

```
Sub addNumbers()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim incrementValue As Long

   incrementValue = Cells(3, 10).Value


            For i = 2 To 100
                    Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value + incrementValue
            Next i


End Sub
```

3)Save this code

4)Go to Developer --> Insert --> Form Controls (Button)
This will open the Assign MAcro window. Select addNumbers. Click on OK.

5) Now you can enter the Desired values in Cell J3 and then click on this button. It will increment Cells B2:B100 by that particular value.